# How do you create a function that takes an argument and returns a dictionary of character counts in Python 3.10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, count

I would like to create a function that takes an argument and creates a dictionary where:

I) the keys are the individual characters of the argument, and

ii) the values represent the number of occurrences of that particular character in the argument.

I have been shown the example below, which although works - lines 4 and 5 don't seem instinctual to me.

Perhaps it's because I'm new to coding. Why should the code need to check an empty dictionary? Is there a more intuitive way?

```
def count_letters(text):
  result = {}
  for letter in text:
    if letter not in result:
      result[letter] = 0
    result[letter] += 1
  return result

print(count_letters("Python"))
```

Comment: You're not checking for an empty dictionary, you're checking to see if a letter is a valid key in the dictionary.  Completely different thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't check if `letter` is in `result` first, then

```
result[letter] += 1
```

will raise a `KeyError`, because there's no value to increment yet.

---

This is a common pattern (add a key if it doesn't exist yet, then do something with its value) captured by the `defaultdict` type.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def count_letters(text):
    result = defaultdict(int)
    for letter in text:
        # If letter isn't in result yet, implicitly execute
        # result[letter] = int() first.
        # int() returns 0.
        result[letter] += 1
    return result
```

---

Counting items in an iterable value is *also* a common pattern, so it might not be surprising that there's a type for that as well.

```
from collections import Counter

def count_letters(text):
    # Counter is a subclass of dict,
    # so you can do with it anything you
    # would do with the dict.
    return Counter(text)
```